# C# for those who are good in Math

Tags: c#, java, vb.net

I've a number Between 10 and 30, I need to present this number in 4 operation addition or subtraction but both should be present at least one time so always we need to use addition and subtraction at least one time.

Here is an example:

The number is 21 I need to generate: 5+6 , 8-5, 9-4, 1+1   (11+3+5+2)=21 (or any other combination equals to 21)

I need generate 4 operations for any number between 10 and 30

anyone could help me out?

If you have a sample in Java, C# or VB it works for me.

Comment: Do you want to find all permutations or any one permutation of 4 addition/subraction problems of which the sum is equal to the input?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: You might at least think about how you would approach the problem, seeing as how it's homework and all.  I mean, you're not going to learn anything about solving problems if you depend on somebody else to give you the solution.

Comment: @user508412 - we ask what you've tried because spoon feeding you the entire solution is not this sites intent. How do you know you "can't" solve it if you haven't even started anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, customize it to meet your needs:

```
Random rn = new Random();
        int a, b, c, d;

        int min = 3, max = 10;
        int desired = 30;
        while
            (
            (
            (a = rn.Next(min, max))
            + (b = rn.Next(min, max))
            + (c = rn.Next(min, max))
            + (d = rn.Next(min, max))
            )
            != desired
            ) { }

        int x = rn.Next(-1* (a - 1 ), a - 1);
        int y = rn.Next(-1 * (b - 1), b - 1);
        int z = rn.Next(-1 * (c - 1), c - 1);
        int v = rn.Next(-1 * (d - 1), d - 1);

        string result =
            (x >= 0 ? (a - x) + "+" + x : (a + -1 * x) + "-" + -1 * x) + " + " +
            (y >= 0 ? (b - y) + "+" + y : (b + -1 * y) + "-" + -1 * y) + " + " +
            (z >= 0 ? (c - z) + "+" + z : (c + -1 * z) + "-" + -1 * z) + " + " +
            (v >= 0 ? (d - v) + "+" + v : (d + -1 * v) + "-" + -1 * v);
```

Comment: You are my Hero Andrzej. You save me a Lot of headaches

Answer (score 1):

Homework?

You could try to split this into two operations:

- write the target number as a sum of 4 numbers
- write those numbers as addition or subtraction.

You do know about [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)? You could use that to generate some numbers, then try if you can make them "fit".

Answer (score 1):

i once found decent solution about this. but sadly forgot. but what i found is the guy implement by using LINQ mixed with random operator to get all possibility as IEnumerable and .First() to do the magic.

Comment: Thanks nice aproach, i didn't think in LINQ, but I'm planning also to port it to JAVA so LINQ could be a limitation